# Can the Visual Studio "Web Setup Project" deployment project create FTP sites?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis

I'm kind of hoping the answer will be "No, it will only create a single Web Site, and not an FTP Site", since I'm half way through writing some WMI code to create the FTP site.